# Error while debugging Windows Phone 8.1 app on device

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, deploying

I try to debug my windows 8.1 application on the device (lumia 630) but I get the following error:

"The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

The application is installing and I can run it without problems on the device. I also can debug the application in the emulator. The only problem appears when trying to debug on the device. I tried everything I could find with a google search...This inclues restarting the Windows Phone IP over USB service, reinstalling the W8 SDK, un-installing the app before debugging.

If someone has an idea, no matter how stupid it is I would like to hear it. I really need the phone debugging.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It just randomly started after the denim update to my 1520.

Comment: I managed to get this to work by removing the SD card from the phone and then . This is really stupid and hopefully it will start working again with an update.

Comment: Same problem here with a Lumia 830. We have several Windows phones, all debugging fine, but the 830 is reporting the message as above. I'm therefore convinced its a device issue rather than Visual Studio.